# LARAVEL - Unread messages notifications in all pages

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

in my project i have front and back office.

I have this

InfoController

```
 //unread messages
 public function naoLido(){

        $infos = PedidoInfo::where('lido',0)->get();

        return view('layoutadmin' ,compact('infos'));
    }
```

this works,  but how can I use this in all pages?
I have an layoutAdmin.blade.php where i had the menus and i want put the number or unread messages there like that, but i have in one page, how can i display in all pages?

```
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Informações 
       @if ($infosL -> count() > 0)
            { $infosL -> count() }}
       @endif
 <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers) for that.

> View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a view is rendered. If you have data that you want to be bound to a view each time that view is rendered, a view composer can help you organize that logic into a single location.